# Why need to set public before override viewDidLoad in a public access control viewController

Tags: ios, swift, public

Why need to set public before override viewDidload in a public access control viewController

```
public class customViewController: UIViewController {
    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

if I remove the public, Xcode will give an error warning!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error message is fairly explicit:

> Overriding instance method must be as accessible as the declaration it
>   overrides.

This means that a method must not have a lower access level than the method it overrides.

For example given this class:

```
public class Superclass {
    internal func doSomething() {
        ...
    }
}
```

You cannot then override `doSomething` with a method that is less accessible than `interal`. e.g.

```
public class Subclass : Superclass {
    // error
    private override func doSomething() {
    }
}
```

You can however override a method and make it **more** accessible:

```
public class Subclass : Superclass {
    public override func doSomething() {
        // You can even call the internal method in the superclass
        super.doSomething()
    }
}
```

The [reference documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html) has lots of detail on this, but seems to leave this relationship to implication.

Comment: I think the override access control level can not be lower than the minimum level between the class's level and the method's level.

Answer (score 1):

Took from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html)

`Public` access enables entities to be used within any source file from their defining module, and also in a source file from another module that imports the defining module. You typically use public access when specifying the public interface to a framework.

`Internal` access enables entities to be used within any source file from their defining module, but not in any source file outside of that module. You typically use internal access when defining an app’s or a framework’s internal structure.

`Private` access restricts the use of an entity to the enclosing declaration. Use private access to hide the implementation details of a specific piece of functionality.

`File-private` access restricts the use of an entity to its own defining source file.

Do you need public modifier? You can write it like this:

```
class customViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

No warnings

Comment: The example code given actually creates an `internal` `customViewController` class since that is the default access level when none is specified.

Comment: Thank you! I understand the difference between the access control levels. I really puzzled why I add public give me an error. I think the override access control level can not be lower than the minimum level between the class's level and the method's level.

Comment: In Swift 3 private access restricts the use of an entity to the enclosing declaration, while fileprivate restricts the use to the source file.

Answer (score 0):

You class declaration is:

`public class customViewController: UIViewController`

This opens the `customViewController` up to `public` access (publicly inherited)

Writing this gives you error:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

What happened here was an unpleasant interaction between the *default access level* for a method and how *inheritance* handles access levels.

> A subclass must preserve the accessibility of its superclass’s methods
>   wherever the subclass might be used directly. Otherwise, we would
>   violate the substitution principle that allows us to treat all kinds
>   of `UIViewController` as just another `UIViewController`.